# Creating fillable "mini templates"

Tags: abbreviations

I am using somebody else's vim script that has a neat plugin that allows me type in something like `sub<tab>` and it will generate the following for me:

```
sub ___ {
  ___
}
```

The blank lines act like fields. After the code is generated, the cursor is placed at the beginning of the first blank line and I can immediately type in the name of the subroutine. Then I hit the right arrow key and it takes me to the beginning of the next field and I start entering code for the subroutine. I call this a "mini template" for lack of a better term.

This is nice, but I would like the ability to generate different subroutine code for different kinds of subroutines. For example, sometimes I want a subroutine that starts like this:

```
# Example 1:
sub ___ {
  my ( $self, ___, ___ ) = validated_list(
      \@_,
      ___ => { isa => '___' },
      ___ => { isa => '___' },
  );
}
```

Other times I may want a subroutine that starts like this:

```
# Example 2:
sub ___ {
  my $self = shift;
  my ( ___, ___ ) = pos_validated_list(
      \@_,
      { isa => '___' },
      { isa => '___' },
  );
}
```

So I would like to have is something like abbreviations where I would type in `sub1<TAB>` and it would generate the first example and `sub2<TAB>` would generate the second example except it would provide these nice fields that I can fill out.

Are there any plugins that will help me easily generate these different mini templates?

Comment: If you post the example, that creates your existing template, it might be easier to adapt it to different types.

Comment: That part that goes in the .vimrc file looks like this: `call SmartcomAdd( '^\s*sub',   EOL,    " ___ {\n___\n}",                       {'filetype':'perl'} )`

Comment: And where is `SmartcomAdd` defined and how is it defined?

Comment: I can add and modify templates but there is no way to generate different templates. I don't know how to modify the plugin to do that. It's a big hairy beast beyond my skills: https://github.com/thoughtstream/Damian-Conway-s-Vim-Setup/blob/master/plugin/smartcom.vim

I figured something out there like this must exist. Like abbreviations on steroids.

Comment: I'm thinking a poor man's way of doing this is I could do it using abbreviations. And instead blank lines I could put an asterisk. The abbreviation would move the cursor to the first insert point and I could type in the name of the subroutine. Then, using a hotkey, the cursor will jump to the next asterisk, delete it and then put me into insert mode so I could type in the next bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you're looking for is *snippet*. There exist plenty snippet plugins. I'm maintaining mu-template (where snippets can use other snippets as functions call other functions), more popular plugins are snipmate & co.